# Trying to shade area under curve using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, fillbetween

From scanning Q/As here I've learned I need to add the fill between library. However, it is designed to fill between curves and I want to fill between a curve and the axis to indicate the integral. I tried defining a new named path (floor) to be the x-axis between -0.5 and +0.5. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
%
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[name path = parab, domain =-1:1,] {x^2};
        \addplot[name path = floor, draw=none] coordinates {(-0.5,0) (0.5,0)};
        \addplot[color=gray] fill between[of = parab and floor];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Not entirely unexpected but not what I want.
FYI, I tried defining two new paths - vertical lines at -0.5 (left) and +0.5 (right) with fill between [of parab and floor and left and right] but pgfplots didn't like that. Am I approaching this the wrong way or am I just missing a trick in the use of fill between?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand you correctly, but you define `domain =-1:1` for the parabola, so it goes from x=-1 to x=1. Hence, if you want to fill the area between the parabola and a line that is at y=0, you should use `{(-1,0) (1,0)}` as coordinates.

Comment: @JasperHabicht. True about the domain but I want to show the integral from -0.5 to +0.5. Thanks, for flagging what might be a poor explanation on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure whether I understand you correctly, but at least let me try to explain a few things that I think may help you to solve your issue.

First, you draw a parabola with `domain = -1:1` which means that it goes from x = -1 to x = 1. The `fill between` mechanism will output an area between two paths and respect the end points of these paths. So, if you want to have an area that covers the space between the parabola from x = -1 to x = 1, you need to create a line that also goes from x = -1 to x = 1. If you want to shade only a part of this area, you can make use of the `soft clip` option and specify the domain that you wish to shade.

Second, by default plots are surrounded by boxed axes. There is a padding around the actual plot and the axes. If you don't want this, you need to specify `xmin` and `xmax` or `ymin` and `ymax`. You can then shift down the path that you use for the `fill between` effect, so that it matches the position of the lower box axis.

Compare the output of the three plots below:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin = -0.1, ymax = 1.1]
        \addplot[name path = parab, domain = -1:1] {x^2};
        \addplot[name path = floor, draw = none] coordinates {(-1,-0.1) (1,-0.1)};
        \addplot[color=gray] fill between[of = parab and floor];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin = -0.1, ymax = 1.1]
        \addplot[name path = parab, domain = -1:1] {x^2};
        \addplot[name path = floor, draw = none] coordinates {(-1,-0.1) (1,-0.1)};
        \addplot[color=gray] fill between[of = parab and floor, soft clip = {domain = -0.5:0.5}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot[name path = parab, domain = -1:1] {x^2};
        \addplot[name path = floor, draw = none] coordinates {(-1,0) (1,0)};
        \addplot[color=gray] fill between[of = parab and floor, soft clip={domain = -0.5:0.5}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very complete - soft clip is the trick. Thank you.